# WPF C#: How to get treeviewitem header from HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, header, treeview, selecteditem, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am using HierarchicalDataTemplate to build my TreeView dynamicaly and don't know how to get the header of the selected item from treeview.

I tried to get it by the TreeViewItem.Selected event.

```
    private void TreeViewItem_OnItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        string name = item.Header.ToString();
    }
```

but 'item.Header' is of type [Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953599/how-to-insert-a-child-item-in-a-treeview-c-sharp-wpf/%22Node%22)

this is my XAML-code:

```
<Window x:Class="MaschinenStoppScheduler.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:MaschinenStoppScheduler"
    Title="MaschinenStoppScheduler" Height="500" Width="900" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
<Window.DataContext>
    <MyNamespace:MainWindowVM />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TreeView x:Name="TreeViewGroups" TreeViewItem.Selected ="TreeViewItem_OnItemSelected"  
        ItemsSource="{Binding RootNodes}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,28,0,25" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="181" SelectedItemChanged="TreeViewGroups_SelectedItemChanged">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style
            TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyNamespace:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the selected item will be one of the items in RootNodes. Cast it to that type. `Node`, it seems to be. The header will be whatever property of that class you use for the header -- `Name`, it looks like.

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    var treeView = sender as TreeView;

    var selectedNode = treeView.SelectedItem as Node;

    TreeViewItem tvi = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(treeView.SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem;
}
```

`Node` is the class contained in the collection you bound to `ItemsSource` on the `TreeView`. I've also included code demonstrating how to get the selected `TreeViewItem`.

Comment: Done: ((Node)item.Header).Name;

Comment: Thank you! Another question: The SelectedItemChanged event returns for   the SelectedItem null. Could please explain why

Comment: private void TreeViewGroups_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            TreeViewItem treeViewItem = TreeViewGroups.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
        }

Comment: @sanjar14 do you mean when it changes to null?

Comment: in my example "treeViewItem" is always null. And my question is why?

Comment: @sanjar14 `TreeViewGroups.SelectedItem` is not a `TreeViewItem`. It's a `Node`. It's one of the items from the collection you bound to `ItemsSource`. In WPF, you pretty much *never* touch `TreeViewItems`. You give the treeview instance of your class, and it gives you one back when the user selects it. This isn't winforms, things are very different. That's what I meant in my answer "the selected item will be one of the items in RootNodes. Cast it to that type. Node"

Comment: something like this? var treeViewItem = TreeViewGroups.SelectedItem as Node; If so how can i use treeViewItem.IsSelected = false or treeViewItem.Focus() in code behind? Sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: @sanjar14 What is `sender`? Put a breakpoint in the event handler and hover your mouse over `sender`. See what type it is.

Comment: `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` of sender is of type Node

Comment: `sender` is `System.Windows.Controls.TreeView`

Comment: You can get the TreeViewItem from the SelectedItem value like so (not exactly obvious!): http://stackoverflow.com/a/5218687/424129

Comment: It returns also null. The items of `ItemContainerGenerator`are of type Node

Comment: @sanjar14 No, that's not true. Not unless you're passing it garbage. See update to answer. That's working code that I copied directly out of my test project in Visual Studio.

Comment: I just copied your code. It does not work. The problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: @sanjar14 Wait a minute, you're handling ItemSelected in your question. I did a handler for SelectedItemChanged. Different events. I goofed. Which did you use my handler for?

Comment: The problem with the handler `TreeViewItem.Selected` has indeed solved. I'm working now  with the handler `SelectedItemChanged`. There I copied your code in it and set the value IsSelected of the current TreeViewItem to false.

Comment: I'm using the same handler like you

Comment: @sanjar14 So what didn't work, just deselecting? You're not going to be able to deselect in the selection changed event. What you could try doing is BeginInvoke with the idle state flag, so your code will happen after the event finishes -- I don't recall the details but here are lots of examples around here

Comment: @sanjar14 maybe not examples for TreeView selection in particular, more like changing a bound property back to its original value when a binding updates it. Same principle.

Comment: No it returns null by selecting. With `BeginInvoke` it does not work unfortunately. Can I send you my program and you looking at why it does not work?

Comment: @sanjar14 1. Call `BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, (Action)()=>{...})`. That way, the lambda is invoked *after* the SelectedItemChanged event is fully complete. 2. ALL code that you want to execute after the event handler MUST go in the lambda. ALL OF IT. You left the important part in the handler where you already know it won't work. 3. I think that sleazy file transfer site gave me a virus. Use DropBox instead, it's safe and it's free. 4. That's two answers for the price of one, you owe me another 15 pts ha ha.

Comment: I have followed the steps you have described, but "tvi" always has the value null. Set a breakpoint at the if statement in lambda expression and you will see it. Here my programm again. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ar1pqoglsxm8wjc/WpfTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: @sanjar14 See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6713032/424129): It's ugly. However, I'm even uglier, so I wrote a nice little generic recursive extension method. Since the question has been asked before, and all the answers are either "good luck writing your own" or else truly horrible code, why don't you ask that as a separate question, and I'll answer it with my recursive thing.